# URLsearchparams typescript error. I can't convert the object to string using toString()

Tags: typescript, postgresql, express, backend, urlsearchparams

I am creating a react app with postgres, express, node, typescript. But i encountered a problem while creating backend code. There is a error while using URLsearchparams.

**index.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import * as recipeAPI from './recipe-api'


const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.get("/api/recipe/search", async (req,res) => {
    const searchTerm = req.query.searchTerm as string;
    const page = parseInt(req.query.page as string);
  
    const results = await recipeAPI.searchRecipes(searchTerm, page);
    return res.json(results);
})

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("Server running on localhost 5000")
})
```

**recipe-api-ts**

```
import { error } from "console";
import { URLSearchParams } from "url"

const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;

export const searchRecipes = async (searchTerm: string, page: number) => {
    if(!API_KEY){
        throw new Error("API key not found")
    }



const baseURL = "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch";
const url = new URL(baseURL);

const queryParams = {
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    query: searchTerm,
    number: 10,
    offset: (page - 1) * 10,
  };

  const searchTerms = new URLSearchParams(queryParams);

  url.search = searchTerms.toString();

  try {
    const searchResponse = await fetch(url.toString());
    const resultsJson = await searchResponse.json();
    return resultsJson;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

getting error in recipe-api-ts file in this line `const searchTerms = new URLSearchParams(queryParams);`

TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/recipe-api.ts:23:43 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ apiKey: string; query: string; number: number; offset: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | URLSearchParams | Record<string, string | readonly string[]> | Iterable<[string,
string]> | readonly [string, string][] | undefined'.
Type '{ apiKey: string; query: string; number: number; offset: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string | readonly string[]>'.
Property 'number' is incompatible with index signature.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | readonly string[]'.

23   const searchTerms = new URLSearchParams(queryParams);

This is error after compile shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URLSearchParams only accepts string values in your object number and offset values are of type number which is causing this error convert it to string to fix this error

```
const queryParams = {
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    query: searchTerm,
    number: `10`,
    offset: `${(page - 1) * 10}`,
  };

const searchTerms = new URLSearchParams(queryParams);
```